# Unique rows based on a specific column containing multiple strings

Tags: r, split, unique

I would like to split my data.frame, `all`, into unique rows based on the `value` column:

`all` dataframe:

```
seq  start  value
ch1   20    "NE001", "NE002"
ch2   30    "NE002", "NE003"
ch3   40    "NE001", "NE002", "NE003"
```

My expected output:

```
seq  start  value
ch1   20    NE001
ch1   20    NE002
ch2   30    NE002
ch2   30    NE003
ch3   40    NE001
ch3   40    NE002
ch3   40    NE003
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I am suspicious about the format of your `value` column. Are you sure each element of `value` is a comma separated string of quoted substrings? Maybe include the `dput` output for the example data you've shown us.

Comment: Yes, the original format was like `c("NE001", "NE001")` and so on, in `value` collumn. I used gsub exclude parenthesis.

Comment: @jbaums this is perfectly possible.... `data.frame( x = I(list( 1:2) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one slightly fiddly way to achieve it.

```
d <- data.frame(seq=c('ch1', 'ch2', 'ch3'),
                start=c(20, 30, 40),
                value=c('"NE001", "NE002"',
                        '"NE002", "NE003"',
                        '"NE001", "NE002", "NE003"'))

# sub out quotes and split values into vectors
v <- strsplit(gsub('"', '', d$value), ', ')  

cbind(d[rep(seq_along(v), sapply(v, length)), 1:2], 
      value=unlist(v))

#     seq start value
# 1   ch1    20 NE001
# 1.1 ch1    20 NE002
# 2   ch2    30 NE002
# 2.1 ch2    30 NE003
# 3   ch3    40 NE001
# 3.1 ch3    40 NE002
# 3.2 ch3    40 NE003
```

Remove row.names as required.